# Google Analytics session scope custom dimension not showing data in widget

Tags: google-analytics, session

I have a web application in which at the time of login I am setting the custom dimension. The scope of the dimension is "Session". The value of the custom dimension can be US or UK markets. When the user logins then he make some clicks and I want that clicks to be captured by market wise.

The issue here is my custom dimension is not giving appropriate data even after 2 days. Either UK market's data is missed out or sometimes US's market data. Sometimes both markets' data gets combined.

[image]